# Asymptotic distribution of $\bar{X}_n^k$

Tags: distributions, self-study, estimation, asymptotics

Suppose $(X_n)$ are iid with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$. Then by CLT $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n-\mu) \overset{D}{\rightarrow} N(0,\sigma^2)$ and use delta method we can get the asymptotic distribution for $\bar{X}_n^k$ that is $\sqrt{n}(\bar{X}_n^k-\mu^k) \overset{D}{\rightarrow} k\mu^{k-1}N(0,\sigma^2)$, where $k \in \mathbb{N}$ and assume $\mu \neq 0$.

My question is how to obtain the asymptotic distribution for $\bar{X}_n^k$ when $\mu=0$? Do I need to use "k-th" order delta method? i.e. use k-th order taylor approximation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, this situation (ie $g'$ vanishing at the limit of $\bar{X}_n$) is what the higher-order delta method is for.
However, in this case, $g(x) = x^k$ is sufficiently simple that we can compute the limiting distribution directly.

By the CLT, $\sqrt{n} \bar{X}_n \stackrel{\mathrm{d}}{\rightarrow} \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$, from which we find that the limiting distribution
$$
n^{k/2} \bar{X}_n^k
= (\sqrt{n} \bar{X}_n)^k
\stackrel{\mathrm{d}}{\rightarrow} \sigma^k Z^k,
$$
where $Z \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 1)$.

As an exercise, you can verify that the $k$th order delta method peprforms this exactl calculation, but with some superfluous extra steps.